# android download zip files from the url using robospice in post method

Tags: android, robospice

how can i download files (may any kind of file) using robospice in the post method

i'm using Bitmap directly like ...

```
imageRequest = new BitmapRequest(
                    ConfigurationBean.getNursery_url()
                            + "/api/v1/downloadPractitionersPhoto.php?nursery_id="
                            + ConfigurationBean.getNursery_id(), cacheFile);
```

using this i'm able to download a files but i need to have inparam in this url

but here i'm struggling to give input or inparam for the REST service ,can any one help

Comment: Where is the post method? `i need to have inparam in this url` ? Show exactly what you want to put in it please.

Comment: here what i do just calling the url and using the parameter like nursery_id=(some value ), so this passing values can consider as GETmethod samething i want as POSTmethod

Comment: You are using a GET method now indeed. So you are not using a POST method as mentioned in the subject. You want to know if there is a post method in ConfigurationBean and if yes what is the function name.

Comment: yes you are right, i need that how to use post method to download file,even if BigBinaybitmap also no problem ,give me the code guide me how use that